# Parse Json to Map<String,String> kotlin multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

My resialized is "{"2":"Hello","Tesst":"Value"}"

I tried to parse this string to Map<String,String>

```
            val resialized = readFile(createStorageDirectoryPath(getManifestFilePath()), MANIFEST_FILE_NAME, errorOut)
                manifest = Json.decodeFromString(/*serializer*/, resialized)
```

How I create a serializer for Map<String,String>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use an other version of `decodeFromString` which will take care of `deserializer` by itself.

```
import kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString

val res = Json.decodeFromString<Map<String, String>>("{\"2\":\"Hello\",\"Tesst\":\"Value\"}")
```

It's marked with `ExperimentalSerializationApi`, but I had no problems using it for the last year. This method is recommended by [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html#example-json-serialization).